# Third party modules in mailalert on prestashop

Tags: php, module, content-management-system, prestashop

I have a custom module that I'm using on prestashop 1.5.4.1 and I need to show some information on the new_order email.
I'm quite new to prestashop and it's the first time I'm messing with it.. I wanna know how I can get the variable of that module and show it on the email template.

I already found where the new_order mail variables are set, but don't know how I can add my new custom variable to it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the custom variable that you want to add?

Comment: I have a 'delivery scheduled' module, and I need to pass the scheduled date of the order delivery in the mail..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the PaymentModule class and add your custom variable to the email template.

Copy the `validateOrder` method from `classes/PaymentModule.php`

Create `override/classes/PaymentModule.php` and paste the `validateOrder` method:

```
<?php
class PaymentModule extends PaymentModuleCore
{
  //paste validateOrder here
}
```

Find the following line in `validateOrder`:

```
'{delivery_other}' => $delivery->other,
```

After that line assign your custom variable. For example:

```
'{delivery_date}' => $myDeliveryDate,
```

Remove `/cache/class_index.php` to clear the cache.

Copy `order_conf.html` and `order_conf.txt` from `mails/en` to `themes/YOURTHEME/mails/en` if they are not already there. This will prevent PrestaShop updates to overwrite your changes.

Add your custom variable to the new `order_conf.html` and `order_conf.txt`. For example:

```
<tr>
  <td align="left">Delivery date: {delivery_date}</td>
</tr>
```